# Using LightBox 2 in Ruby on Rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, lightbox, lightbox2

I have done a lot of web searches to see if I could find a script where I could popup a QR code image in my Rails application.  I came across Lightbox 2.  I have installed the scripts and copied the CSS code in my stylesheet.

I tried to use the following code.  I tried to include the path where the image is located.  The page displays fine when QR Code is clicked but there is no image.

```
<a href="QR-Code-image.jpg" rel="lightbox">QR Code</a>
```

I would like to know if I can define the path for this image using the code above or will I need to use some kind of rails statement to do this?

I have been doing searching for a couple of hours and had found several suggestions, including on Stack Overflow. However I have not seen any examples that stated that they were used in Rails applications.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the only thing u need is a right path to image...QR-Code-image.jpg means that your image is in public folder...

Comment: It is currently in app/assets/images where I believe the link_to image_tag looks for images.  I tried adding that in front of the filename but it still did not find it.  So if I put the graphic in the public folder of my Rails app this code should find the image?

Comment: if so then <a href="/assets/QR-Code-image.jpg" rel="lightbox">QR Code</a> should work... u can use path_to_image helper to generate href  => link_to image_tag(name), path_to_image(name), :rel => "lightbox"

Comment: Yuri, I will try that.  I am currently using the Accordion javascript.  When I installed lightbox it apparently overrode the option to hide the accordion body sections when the page first displays.  Once I figure that out I will try lightbox again with your code suggestion.

Comment: That did the trick.  I was also able to figure out how to change my HTML5 code and javascript for the accordion to load the page with the accordion items closed.  Now I need to figure out which image it uses for closing the image and get it in assets.  The one I thought it used does not work.  Very minor issue.  Thanks so much for the input.  Next I will try to install a carousel script that uses links.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

> inside the html.erb file

```
<%= link_to image_tag("small_image", :size => "76x76"),'/assets/large_image.png',:rel => "lightbox"%>
```

**image_tag** is for show small thumbnail preview, make sure actual image path is `/assets/image_file`

> if you use ordinary html tags its fine

```
<a href="/assets/images_file" rel="lightbox" >My Image</a>
```

Comment: I ended up creating a QR code page with the ones we wanted.  I may try this again.  Thanks so much for the info.  I am doing a lot of streamlining of the code so using this may help with that process.